# Why the equal matrix show different picture?

Tags: matlab

I write a function using matlab. I want to divide a picture into 4(2*2)part. My code is

```
function [new_file] = divide( input_file) 
    picture_file = imread(input_file);  % read input picture file
    [rows , cols , colors] = size(picture_file);
    n=2;
    height = floor(rows/n);
    width = floor(cols/n);

    new_file = zeros(height*n, width*n, colors);
    for i = 1:n
        for j = 1:n
            temp = picture_file((i-1)*height+1:i*height,(j-1)*width+1:j*width,:);
            new_file((i-1)*height+1:i*height,(j-1)*width+1:j*width,:) = temp;
            figure;
            imshow(temp);
            figure;
            imshow(new_file((i-1)*height+1:i*height,(j-1)*width+1:j*width,:));
        end
    end

end
```

`temp` and `new_file((i-1)*height+1:i*height,(j-1)*width+1:j*width,:)` are the equal matrix. But imshow different pictures. Why happen that?

Comment: `picture_file` is read in as some integer type, likely `uint8`, and hence `temp` is too. But you initialize `new_file` as `double`. You can correct this by adding `'uint8'` to the end of the `zeros` call.

Comment: @CrisLuengo, Thanks very much. It worked.